# Github Secret not found in System.getenv

Tags: android, gradle, yaml, github-actions, bintray

I've 3 secrets in my Github repo's settings, an action `workflow.yml` file where:

```
...
- name: Uploading to Bintray
   env:
     s1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ONE }}
     s2: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TWO }}
     s3: ${{ secrets.SECRET_THREE }}
   run: ./gradlew bintrayUpload
```

And my `deploy.gradle`:

```
configure<BintrayExtension> {
    var ossPwd = ""
    if (project.rootProject.file("local.properties").exists()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
        ossPwd = System.getenv("s3") ?: ""
    }

    pkg.apply {
    ...
        version.apply {
            if (ossPwd.isNotEmpty())
                mavenCentralSync.apply {
                    ...
                    password = ossPwd
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`System.getenv("s3")` throws `null` while *SECRET_ONE* and *SECRET_TWO* are fetched correctly.
Any reason why?

**EDIT:**
I've just deleted (for the 10th time) my SECRET_THREE and created another 2 secrets. All 4 were found and correctly used... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: The env setup is at the step level so doubt is getting overwritten in the workflow. Please check that you defined the secrets name properly, or check within your run command to make sure it isn’t getting overwritten. Also rename the s3 env to something else as a test.

Comment: I've double checked all secrets including delete/create again. The workflow last step is posted above, s3 it's not overwritten. My `deploy.gradle` does not override s3 also. Both s1 and s2 are OK and the logic it's the same, so strange... I've updated my question with a little bit more of code.

Comment: @GuilhE Can you set `s3` as `System.getenv("s3") ?: "xxx"`, just to double-check it is defined there, and would have an "`xxx`" value?

Comment: I've just deleted (for the 10th time) my SECRET_THREE and created another 2 secrets. All 4 were found and correctly used... ¯_(ツ)_/¯
I've added this: `println("s3"+System.getenv("s3").isNullOrEmpty+"s4"+System.getenv("s4").isNullOrEmpty)` and it shown `s3falses4false` and it worked...

Comment: @GuilhE Strange indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. This kind of issue is usually a secrets typo.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the GitHub Actions [workflow syntax for `env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env), all I can see is:

> When more than one environment variable is defined with the same name, GitHub uses the most specific environment variable.
>
> - an environment variable defined in a step will override job and workflow variables with the same name, while the step executes.
> - A variable defined for a job will override a workflow variable with the same name, while the job executes.

So make sure nothing is overriding `SECRET_THREE` or `s3` itself.

---

The OP mentions in the comments:

> I've just deleted (for the 10th time) my `SECRET_THREE` and created another 2 secrets.
> All 4 were found and correctly used... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
>
> I've added this:
>
> ```sh
> println("s3"+System.getenv("s3").isNullOrEmpty+\
> "s4"+System.getenv("s4").isNullOrEmpty
> ```
>
> and it shown `s3falses4false` and it worked.

Comment: SECRET_THREE is a secret not an env so this doesn’t apply. It is more probable that OP is not setting the secret properly through a typo or overriding env s3 somewhere inside the run script

Comment: @EdwardRomero https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets: "To make a secret available to an action, you must set the secret as an input or environment variable in the workflow file. " That is what the OP did.

Comment: yes, but he is already at the step level as you can see from the run command. So nothing to override the env. If he would have added it at the job or workflow level, I would agree with your answer. But he’s not.